# Maximum and minimum values of unions and intersections

Tags: probability

If P(A) = 0.3 and P(B) = 0.9, find
(a) the maximum possible value of P(A ∪ B);
(b) the minimum possible value of P(A ∪ B);
(c) the maximum possible value of P(A ∩ B);
(d) the minimum possible value of P(A ∩ B).

Is it correct to say that max value of P(A ∪ B) = 1? I know P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B), but 0.9 + 0.3 = 1.2 and this isn't possible.

Minimum value of P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B), 0.9 + 0.3 - 0.27 = 0.93

Maximum value of P(A ∩ B) =  P(A) x P(B) = 0.9 x 0.3 = 0.27

Minimum value of P(A ∩ B) = 0 if A and B are disjoint and can't occur together

I'd really appreciate any feedback on whether I have this correct. Thank you

Comment: "*I know $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$, but...*"  No, that is not correct.  That is only correct when $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$, for example when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: "*Maximum value of $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times\Pr(B)$*"  Again, no this is incorrect.  That is only correct when $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following:

- $\Pr(A\cup B)\geq \Pr(A)$ by monotonicity
- $\Pr(A\cap B) \leq \Pr(A)$ also by monotonicity
- $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B) -\Pr(A\cap B)$ by inclusion-exclusion
- $0\leq \Pr(A)\leq 1$

---

For your specific problem, you are told $\Pr(A)=0.3$ and $\Pr(B)=0.9$.

$0.9=\Pr(B)\leq \Pr(A\cup B)$ so $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is bounded below by $0.9$.  This is a tight lower bound since it is possible that $A\subseteq B$ in which case $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is exactly equal to $0.9$.  For instance, where we have the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,9\}$.

$\Pr(A\cup B)\leq 1$ since it is a probability.  This is a tight upper bound since it is possible that $\Pr(A\cup B)=1$.  For instance, where we have the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4,\dots,10\}$.

$\Pr(A\cap B)\leq \Pr(A)=0.3$ by monotonicity.  This is a tight upper bound since it is possible that $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.3$.  For instance, where we have the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,9\}$.

$\Pr(A\cap B)\geq 0.2$, this one is a bit trickier to see.  Yes, it is bounded below by zero as you note, but that bound is not tight.  Instead, here we have $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B)$ by rearranging the inclusion-exclusion identity and note that $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is minimized when $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is maximized.  We have that $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is maximized when it is equal to $1$ so it follows that $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is minimized at $0.3+0.9-1=0.2$.  This bound is tight, for example where we have the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,\dots,10\}$.

---

As alluded in the comments above, $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is not necessarily equal to $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.  That is only guaranteed true when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint which is not generally the case.  Instead, the general identity is $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.

Similarly, $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not necessarily equal to $\Pr(A)\times\Pr(B)$.  That is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent events which is not generally the case.  Instead, the general identity is $\Pr(A\cap B) =\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$